# Filling array of arrays

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to calculate the correlation and store the values in an array of arrays. It seems like the problem is filling vectors into a vector. I have tried some solutions but no luck. I appreciate your help.

```
void BuildCorrelationForMatrix()
{
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<correlation>> m_correlationMatrix;
std::vector<std::vector<float>> m_correlationValues;
std::vector<float> row_values;
float value_inrow ;

for(int col_idx = 0; col_idx < (int) m_correlationData.size(); ++col_idx){
  for(int col_idy = 0; col_idy < (int) m_correlationData.size();++col_idy){
            
  auto data1= m_correlationData[col_idx];  
  auto data2= m_correlationData[col_idy];
                              
  m_correlationMatrix.push_back(std::make_unique<correlation>(data1, data2);
            
  value_inrow = m_correlationMatrix[col_idy]->CalculateCorrelation();
  row_values.push_back(value_inrow);

  // m_correlationValues[col_idx][col_idy]=value_inrow; //not works
    }

  m_correlationValues[col_idx].push_back(row_values); // problem is here!
 //m_correlationValues[col_idx]=row_values; // not works
                       
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> m_correlationValues;
```

This creates a new vector. This vector is completely empty. There's nothing in it.

```
 m_correlationValues[col_idx].push_back(row_values);
```

The `[]` operator accesses ***existing*** values in the vector. It does ***not*** add values to a vector. It doesn't matter what `col_idx` is, here. This is accessing non-existent index in a vector, which is undefined behavior and the reason for your crash.

Note that for the 2nd level in this two-dimensional vector the shown code correctly uses `push_back` to add values to the 2nd dimension of this vector.

Observe that `col_idx` iterates between 0 and `m_correlationData.size()-1`, according to the outer `for` loop. Therefore, it should be possible to fix this crash simply by adding

```
m_correctionValues.resize(m_correlationData.size());
```

at the beginning of this function.

Comment: Thank you! I've added this. However, I got this error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<float>::push_back(std::vector<float>&)'
 m_correlationValues[col_idx].push_back(row_values);

Comment: @CananFirat Thats because you are trying to add 3rd vector to an already initialized 2D vectors, you can do a dirty fix by 

```m_correlationValues[col_idx] = std::vector<float>(row_values.size()); for(int i = 0; i < row_values.size(); i++){
    m_correlationValues[col_idx][i] = row_values[i];
}```
or use your commented one ```m_correlationValues[col_idx]=row_values```

Comment: Thank you so much both! It seems like working now